# On a Mac, how do you recover from accidentally removing a device from the sidebar?

Tags: macos, finder, sidebar

So I've got my Nook plugged into my Mac and it shows a "No Name" device for my additional memory. I try to rename it, but instead of clicking rename in Finder, I accidentally click "Remove from Sidebar".

How do I get it back on the Finder's sidebar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if it shows up under *sidebar* in Finder Preferences.
Click on your desktop, open the *Finder* menu and select *preferences*

Comment: Clicking hard disks brought it back. Many Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisA, link down..

Answer (score 0):

After removing the sidebar item, if it does not disappear, just logout and login.